# Problem in finding the least number in the array in C

Tags: c, loops

This is the C program that I've written to find the least element in the given array.

But the output is "0" every time. I've checked other websites too but I found no problem in my program.
Can anyone please rectify the problem in this program. (Thanks in advance)

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i,least,x[10];
    printf("Enter the elements into the array\n");

    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x[10]);
    }
    least=x[0];
    for (i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(least > x[i])
        {
            least=x[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The least element in the array is %d", least);
 }
```

Comment: You may want to check your understanding of: 1) the number of elements `x` has space for. 2) What `&x[10]` means.

Comment: Should be voted to be closed as a typo.

Comment: You want `&x[i]` in your `scanf()`. Right now you always wrote to the 11th element of the array, leading to a buffer overflow btw.

Comment: When you fill an array you should write scanf("%d",&x[i]); (each case has one value) but in your code you write scanf("%d",&x[10]); so you fill the 10th case for 10 times

Comment: @Jarvis it's true that when the typo is corrected, there is no more question! ;)

Answer (score 8):

In your code

```
 scanf("%d",&x[10]);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%d",&x[i]);
              ^^^
```

as you'd need to loop over the array element by element and the counter is `i`.

Also, by using index 10 on a 10-element array, you're off-by-one, accessing out of bound memory and invoking undefined behavior.

That said,

- Use a proper signature for `main()`, for a hosted one, the minimalistic one would be `int main(void)`.
- Always check for success of `scanf()` for user inputs. Avoid using `scanf()` at all costs, use `fgets()` for better.

Comment: Thanks. How much time did you take to spot that?